# Proper error handling for HTTP triggered Function?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

What is the proper way to do error handling for HTTP triggered Azure Functions v2? Should - as recommend in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51212313/1537195) - all inner exceptions be caught and nothing ever be thrown?

I.e. always surround everything you do inside your function with try-catch, like this:

```
[FunctionName("DemoHttpFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        await InnerDoSomething();
        return new NoContentResult();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogError(ex, "Something went wrong");
        return new StatusCodeResult(500);
    }
}
```

Drawbacks I see with that are

1. No error message at all gets returned to the user. `StatusCodeResult` does not provide any overload to supply a message
2. All executions of your function will show as successful, e.g. in the logging in Application Insights.

Comment: [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages#handing-errors-in-functions) : `For the other Functions triggers, there is no built-in retry when errors occur during function execution. To prevent loss of trigger information should an error occur in your function, we recommend that you use try-catch blocks in your function code to catch any errors. When an error occurs, write the information passed into the function by the trigger to a special "poison" message queue. This approach is the same one used by the Blob storage trigger.`

Comment: thanks, but it's not about retry. It's rather if there is some internal exception and I want to tell that to the caller, how do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

> No error message at all gets returned to the user. `StatusCodeResult` does not provide any overload to supply a message

You are in control of the code. You can easily use a different result that would include your desired information.

```
//...

catch(Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError(ex, "Something went wrong");
    var model = new { error = "User friendly something went wrong" };
    return new ObjectResult(model) {
        StatusCode = 500
    };
}

//...
```

Comment: thanks, the code snippet makes sense! Regarding the try-catch, as I wrote in the comment above, my question isn't about retry. More about how to properly log errors (also to appinsights) and return something meaningful to the user

Comment: @silent I'm checking the second part of your question to see if there is a way to plug into insights. But it should be able to flag the server error response returned from the function.